# Excel array formula for comparing two lists

Tags: excel, array-formulas

Say I have a list of hours per week one is allowed to work (40, 32, 40, 40.. etc) and a large list of actual worked hours for each employee, it might look something like that:

```
Hours allowed 40 40 32 40 28 40 40
Worked  Emp1  40 40 32 40 28 40 40 (false)
        Emp2  40 40 32 42 28 40 40 (true)
```

I would like a single-cell formula for each employee which compares each element of the worked hour list with the corresponding element of the hours allowed list returning TRUE if there is one or more instance of worked hours being over hours allowed.  So for the table above it would return FALSE for the first line and TRUE for the second one (there is one instance of worked hours being more than weekly allowed hours).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  Almost as soon as I posted the question I remembered the answer :)

In case if anyone is interested, the formula is:
    {=SUM(--(list1>list2))}